# How to copy and paste a range from one workbook to another more efficiently in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have figured out how to copy and paste from one workbook to another but it is not the most efficient. I want to copy a range from one workbook and paste it in cell A3 in a second workbook. Here is my code (I have set all my variables, I just did not include it in this question):

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim wb1s1 As Worksheet
Dim wb1s2 As Worksheet
Dim wb2s1 As Worksheet
Dim wb2s2 As Worksheet

    wb1.Activate
       With wb1s1
        .Range(.Range("A14"), .Range("F" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
      End With

    wb2.Activate
        With wb2s1
       .Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
      End With


    wb1.Activate
      With wb1s2
        .Range(.Range("A14"), .Range("F" & .Rows.Count)).Copy
       End With

    wb2.Activate
       With wb2s2
       .Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       End With
```

Now, I have tried this line of code to increase its efficiency but it is not working for me.

```
wb1.wb1s1.Range("A14", ("F" & Rows.Count)).Copy Destination:=wb2.wb2s1.Range("A3")
```

I get the error "Object doesn't support this Property or Method". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of question is better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Please consider posting it there instead.

Comment: @Andrew This question is *not* suitable for Code Review, as the code in it was not working correctly. Notice that he got an error message. Also, just because a question is "better suited" for another site does not mean that it is off-topic here. So even if this *was* fully-working code, it would still be on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: GCC, please do not edit the answer to your question into the question. If you've arrived at your own answer, then you should post it below, in the answer box.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm afraid you're incorrect. He literally says that the code *is* working but wants it to run more efficiently. If this question doesn't make the cut to get moved to Code Review, I wonder what does. Additionally, this question is so incredibly specific to his one-off situation that I strongly doubt many future users (if any) will either (a) find this question when searching for help with their own use-cases or (b) find the answer below useful for improving their own code. In sum, this is nothing but clutter on SO but a Good Question on Code Review, therefore it should be moved.

Comment: @Andre There's an error message displayed right there in the question. This could be *made* suitable for Code Review by editing, but it is not ready for migration *in its current state*, which is all that moderators look at. *"If this question doesn't make the cut to get moved…I wonder what does."* Not much. It's rare that questions asked on one site are sufficiently tailored to the rules of another site that they can be migrated directly. Your "usefulness" justification for migration is...odd. Why do you think a question that is too narrowly scoped to be useful would be useful somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should not double reference the Worksheet.

try

```
wb1s1.Range("A14", ("F" & Rows.Count)).Copy Destination:=wb2s1.Range("A3")
```

The workbook wb1 does not support the "Property or Method" wb1s1, nor does wb2 support wb2s1