# Excel VBA - More efficient way to copy/paste large range of cells from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I am reasonably familiar with VBA however, as it turns out, I still lack experience with Excel VBA. I am currently working on an Excel application for Apple/Mac system, where I need to copy a large range of cells from one workbook to another workbook. The function to do this does its job fine, however it takes quite a long time +/- 2 minutes to complete the procedure. I have tried all kinds of things to speed up this process, but I get stuck in this. The worksheet that needs to be copied is, as mentioned, very large 500 rows and 3600 columns, which amounts to about 1,780,000 cells

```
Function CopyOfferteOverzicht()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sFileName As String
Dim sFileFormat As String

sFileFormat = "{""org.openxmlformats.spreadsheetml.sheet""}"

Dim bOneFile As Boolean
bOneFile = True

Dim sFile As String

Dim wbTarget, wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsTarget, wsSource As Worksheet
Dim rngTarget, rngSource As Range
Dim iChoice As Integer
Dim bSheetExists As Boolean
Dim sSheetName As String
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastRowTarget As Long

Dim iAnswer As Integer

10  Set wbTarget = ThisWorkbook
20  Set wsTarget = wbTarget.Sheets("offerte overzicht")

'Stap 1. Open een dialoogvenster en vraag de gebruiker het bestand te selecteren waarvan deze het offerte overzicht wil kopieren.

30  sFilePath = MacScript("return (path to desktop folder) as String")

Dim sAppleScript As String
40  sAppleScript = _
                "set theFile to (choose file of type" & _
                " " & sFileFormat & " " & _
                "with prompt ""Selecteer het bestand waarvan je het offerte overzicht wilt kopieren."" default location alias """ & _
                sFilePath & """ without multiple selections allowed) as string" & vbNewLine & _
                "return posix path of theFile"

50      sFile = MacScript(sAppleScript)

' Stap 2. Controleer of er een bestand is geselecteerd.
60      If sFile <> "" Then

70          With Application
80              .ScreenUpdating = False
90              .EnableEvents = False
100         End With

110     End If
    
            Dim sSplitFile As Variant
            Dim N As Long
            
120      sSplitFile = Split(sFile, Chr(10))

130      For N = LBound(sSplitFile) To UBound(sSplitFile)

'Stap 3. Bepaal de bestandsnaam (door het padnaam te splitsen) en controleer of het bestand wellicht al is geopend.
140          sFileName = Right(sSplitFile(N), Len(sSplitFile(N)) - InStrRev(sSplitFile(N), _
                Application.PathSeparator, , 1))
                
150         If bBookOpen(sFileName) = False Then

160              Set wbSource = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next

' Stap 4. Open het bestand
165             Application.StatusBar = "Het bestand: " & sFileName & " wordt nu geopend. Even geduld a.u.b..."

170              Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(sSplitFile(N), False, True)

180             If Not wbSource Is Nothing Then

190                 GoTo KopieerWerkblad

200             Else
210                  Application.StatusBar = "Het werblad Offerte overzicht is niet gevonden, de procedure wordt beeindigd."
220                  MsgBox ("Het werblad Offerte overzicht is niet gevonden in het geopende bestand, de procedure wordt beeindigd."), vbCritical, "Offerte overzicht niet gevonden"
                        
230             End If

240          Else

250             Application.StatusBar = "Het geselecteerde bestand is al geopend."
            
260           End If

270        Next N

KopieerWerkblad:

' Stap 5. Activeer het werkblad waarvan je wilt kopieren
280 Set wbSource = Workbooks(sFileName)

'wbSource.Activate (niet nodig)

290 bSheetExists = False

'Stap 6. Controleer of het geopende bestand de sheet "offerte overzicht" bevat, anders geef een foutmelding en breek procedure af

300 Application.StatusBar = "Controleer of het bestand het werkblad offerte overzicht bevat."
310 Call sheetExistsWildcard("?fferte?overzicht", bSheetExists, sSheetName)

320 If bSheetExists = False Then

330      Application.StatusBar = "Er is in het bestand geen werkblad offerte overzicht gevonden. Procedure wordt beeindigd."

335     MsgBox ("In het bestand is geen werkblad offerte overzicht gevonden, procedure wordt beeindigd."), vbCritical + vbOKOnly

340     GoTo ExitProcedure

350 End If

'Stap 7. Controleer of er een filter op het werkblad staat, zo ja verwijder deze dan
360     Application.StatusBar = "Controleer of er in het bestand een filter actief is."

370     If CheckForAutoFilter(sSheetName) = True Then
                Application.StatusBar = "Verwijder het filter."
380         RemoveAutoFilter (sSheetName)
390 End If

'Stap 8. Maak het werkblad Offerte overzicht leeg.

Application.StatusBar = "Maak het werkblad offerte overzicht leeg."

With wbTarget.Worksheets("offerte overzicht")
    .Activate
    lngLastRowTarget = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A:A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A3:ECB" & lngLastRowTarget + 3).ClearContents
End With

'Stap 8. Bepaal het bereik van hetgeen je wilt kopieren

400 With wbSource.Worksheets(sSheetName)
410     .Activate
420     lngLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A:A").End(xlUp).Row
430 End With

'Stap 9. Kopieer het bereik

 'Onderstaande procedure duurt te lang

440 Set rngSource = Range("A2:EFX" & lngLastRow + 1)

460 Application.StatusBar = "Kopieer het bereik A2:EFX" & lngLastRow & "."

470 rngSource.Copy

'Stap 11. Plak het bereik als waarden

480 Application.StatusBar = "Plak het bereik als waarden."

490 Set rngTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("offerte overzicht").Range("A2")

500  rngTarget.PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        operation:=xlNone, _
        skipblanks:=False, _
        Transpose:=False

510 Application.CutCopyMode = False

520 Application.StatusBar = "Kopieren/plakken offerte overzicht voltooid."

530 iAnswer = MsgBox("Kopieren/plakken offerte overzicht voltooid." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Wil je het bestand " & sFileName & " sluiten?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Bronbestand sluiten J/N?")

540 With Application
550      .ScreenUpdating = True
560      .EnableEvents = True
570 End With

580 If iAnswer = vbYes Then
590     wbSource.Close savechanges:=False
600 End If

610 Application.StatusBar = "Klaar!"

620 Set rngSource = Nothing
630 Set rngTarget = Nothing
640 Set wbSource = Nothing
650 Set wbTarget = Nothing

ExitProcedure:

With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
     .EnableEvents = True
End With

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:

If Err.Number = 5 Then
    MsgBox ("Procedure afgebroken door gebruiker"), vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Procedure afgebroken"
    Application.StatusBar = "Procedure afgebroken"
Else
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End If


Resume ExitProcedure

End Function
```

I have tried various copying procedures, have set the screenupdating to false to execute the procedure in the background but it does not seem to help.

I also tried the suggestions by setting the destination range to the source range value as suggested in post [How to copy and paste a range from one workbook to another more efficiently in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44935223/how-to-copy-and-paste-a-range-from-one-workbook-to-another-more-efficiently-in-v)
and
' [Moving large amount of Cells from one Workbook to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721526/moving-large-amount-of-cells-from-one-workbook-to-another)
however I can't seem to get it working.

Maybe it is due to the fact that I am using an Apple/Mac but I can imagine what is the exact cause then. By the way, a similar procedure I use for Windows does do it quickly.

Any help would be appreciated enormously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather that copy/paste, I would use the "this = that" aproach.

```
So, for example: `rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value`
```

It's much faster for larger amounts of data and doesn't involve use of the clipboard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I tried that allready. However I can't seem to get it to work. So you only set the target value to the source value, that's it?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.
Give this a try:
***
`460 Application.StatusBar = "Kopieer het bereik A2:EFX" & lngLastRow & "."

' 470 rngSource.Copy

'Stap 11. Plak het bereik als waarden

480 Application.StatusBar = "Plak het bereik als waarden."

490 Set rngTarget = wbTarget.Worksheets("offerte overzicht").Range("A2")

' 500  rngTarget.PasteSpecial _
        ' Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
        ' operation:=xlNone, _
        ' skipblanks:=False, _
        ' Transpose:=False

' 510 Application.CutCopyMode = False
500 rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value`

Comment: That's it! I finally got it working now, Thank you Russ!